# Nock Headers Authorization forbidden

Tags: javascript, axios, nock

I am trying to nock an axios request. I have successfully mocked the POST request, but it is sending an OPTIONS preflight request. However, I am getting the following error and not sure what to make of it.

```
Error: Headers Authorization forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jsdom? You will most probably need to add the following reply header:

```
'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization'
```

See https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2408.